# Why is SQLAlchemy expecting 6 rows here when I want to delete two?

Tags: sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and I have the following tables:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), primary_key=True))

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    author = db.Column(db.String(64))
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('posts', lazy=True))
    published = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(300), unique=True, index=True)

    def save(self):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = re.sub('[^\w]+', '-', self.title.lower())

    def update_time(self):
        self.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.title)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag {}>'.format(self.tag)
```

Currently I am making a function to allow the user to delete a post entirely with `db.session.delete(post)` and I am getting the follwing error:

`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'tags' expected to delete 6 row(s); Only 2 were matched.`

Why does the delete statement expect 6 rows? 2 is the correct number and corresponds to how many entries there are in the tags table for that post, two unique tags attached to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue here was with my route and not my models.

Bringing the delete function code to the beginning of the route gave me the expected behaviour; the post was deleted from the database and associations in the helper table also removed.

The error was caused by some code in my route that appended selected tags from the submitted form to `post.tags` multiple times over resulting in the expectation of 6 rows.